How to generate unique value for each job in PowerShell GitHub strategy matrix
Below is a sample github workflow in powershell  (part of the code not shared) where i need unique values for psuffix attribute.
    on:
      workflow_call:
        inputs:
            repo:
              description: 'Caller Github repo name'
              required: false
              default: '${{ github.repository }}'
              type: string
            extrachecks_input:
              required: false
              type: string
              default: ''
    
    
        secrets:
          AUTOMATED_TOKEN:
            required: false
    
    
    jobs:
    
      set-global-runner:
        runs-on: '${{ inputs.runner_name }}'
        outputs:
          runner_name: "${{ runner.name }}"
        steps:
          - name: Runner details
            id: runner-dets
            run: |
              echo "Runner Name: ${{ runner.name }}"
              
          - name: Checkout Self workflow
            uses: actions/checkout@v4
            with:
              token: ${{ secrets.AUTOMATED_TOKEN }}
              #path: workspace
              
      set-environment-matrix:
    
      
        name: "Trigger Instances" 
        runs-on: "${{ needs.set-global-runner.outputs.runner_name }}"
        outputs:
          env-matrix: ${{ steps.set-matrix.outputs.ENV-MATRIX }}
          DISMATRIX: ${{ steps.set-matrix.outputs.DISMATRIX }}
          checkencstatus: ${{ steps.set-matrix.outputs.checkencstatus }}
        steps:
    
          - name: prereq
            id: set-matrix
            run: |
              
              ....
              ....
    
              $DISMATRIX="$($dismatrix | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 100)"
              $ENV_VARS="$($EnvNamesJSONVariable | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 100)"
    
              if ($QueryResult.Count -gt 1) {
                echo "Tracker@QueryResult.Count greater than one is $QueryResult.Count"
                echo "DISMATRIX=$DISMATRIX" >> "$env:GITHUB_OUTPUT"
                echo "ENV_VARS=$ENV_VARS" >> "$env:GITHUB_OUTPUT"
              } else {
                echo "Tracker@QueryResult.Count less than one is $QueryResult.Count"
                echo "DISMATRIX=[$DISMATRIX]" >> "$env:GITHUB_OUTPUT"
                echo "ENV-VARS=[$ENV_VARS]" >> "$env:GITHUB_OUTPUT"
              }
    
          
      Trigger_Service:
        name: "${{ matrix.DISPLAYLIST }}"
        needs: [set-environment-matrix, set-global-runner]
        outputs:
          dbsnowgroup: '${{ steps.prereq.outputs.ssnowapp }}' 
        environment: 
          name: ${{ matrix.CUSTOMENVNAME }}
          url: "${{ steps.prereq.outputs.appurl }}"
        runs-on: 
          group: ARE-Shared
        
        strategy:
          matrix: 
            include: ${{fromJSON(needs.set-environment-matrix.outputs.DISMATRIX)}}
          fail-fast: false
          
    
        steps:
    
          
          - name: checkout source
            uses: actions/checkout@v4
            with:
               path: workspace
    
              
          - name: Call to Trigger server
            id: tomcattask-linux
            uses: mmctech/DevOps/integration@master
            env:
              OLToken: '${{ secrets.OL_TOKEN  }}'          
            with:
              psuffix "${{ matrix.customenvName }}_${{ github.run_number }}_${{ github.run_attempt }}"

I tried ${{ matrix.customenvName }}_${{ github.run_number }}_${{ github.run_attempt }} however it is not unique for each job when matrix.customenvName is gets same values?
Need something like unique jobid or rondom unique value for each job please.
How can i give unique value to psuffix?

How fast are these jobs generated? If not too rapid, and enough time to generate the ID, just use DateTime, it can be unique sometimes: (Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMddHHmmssfffffff').... If you can get away with that rather than using the other solutions you are having trouble with—that may simplify it a bit though.
